# MySQL select by difference between lowercase and uppercase characters

Tags: mysql, uppercase, lowercase

I have table like this:

```
Table name: hash_table
----------------
 id        hash
----------------
 1         abc
 2         aBc
 3         abC
 4         AbC
 5         ABc
----------------
```

There is difference between lowercase and uppercase characters. For example `abc` unequal `aBc`.

In this query, return all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `hash_table` WHERE `hash` = "abc"
```

By search in stackoverflow, some answers talk about `UPPER`, `LOWER` and `UCASE` use in select query but they return all rows.

Is there a way to return only correct row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String comparision could be performed in sql in two distinct way  ..binary and not binary .. 
If you don't cast binary  .. the comparision is case insentive .. if you useing binary the  comparision is done by byte and the is also case sensitive  ..

try  using

```
SELECT * FROM `hash_table` WHERE BINARY `hash` = BINARY "abc"
```

Comment: Thank you ❤️ I test this and is correct. But `hash` column is `varchar` and `utf8_general_ci`, This code have not problem by this?

Comment: You can take a look a http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html

Comment: And remember that you can convert the charset and collection on fly if you need ..but in a select shoul be assumed by rdbms  the same charset of the table  .